# Which HTTP/HTTPS www/no-www versions should be registered in Search Console when using Cloudflare Flexible SSL

Tags: seo, google, https, search, cloudflare

I have a question about the use of Cloudflare Flexible SSL and the settings in Google Search Console.

Say I use Flexible SSL on my website example.com. I have wrote a redirect from http to https in my .htaccess so every request on `http://example.com` redirects to `https://example.com`.

What do I need to register on Search Console? Right now I have registered all four possible URLs, meaning `http://example.com`, `https://example.com`, `http://www.example.com` and `https://www.example.com`.

Comment: Why would using Cloudflare be any different from using any other method of implementing HTTPS as far as Search Console is concerned?

Comment: Cloudflare was just an example in this particular situation, I suppose the solution will and should be implemented in every SSL-related matter.

Answer (score 0):

If anything you should choose one url (preferably the one with best ranking) and then redirect all others, then in Google Webmaster Tools enter chosen domain for the preferred URL.

The way you have it set up now, is like having 4 sites all with different ranking.

If you do indeed want to use all 4, you should read this article at Google on [using canonical URLs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en)

Comment: I have set a default URL in Webmaster Tools because otherwise Google will penalize the website for duplicate content. My question was regarding the most suitable method to choose. Register 4 domains and use only one or register only one domain?